# Phaser.js Drag and drop Problems

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am attempting to make a matching game where you have 4 sprites 3 of them have something on them and the other sprite has like anwnser for example the question could be the matching of fractions and decimals and you would have 3 fraction or 3 decimals with one of the oposite as the correct awnser on the other sprite that you match with the correct one. but my problem is that I can not get the sprites to decet that they are colliding. here is what I have so far.

```
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {preload: preload, create: create, update: update});

function preload() {
    game.load.image('Cone','pics/ICE-Cream-cone_1.png');
    game.load.image('back','pics/BakerIceBackground_1.png');
    game.load.image('Shoot','pics/CreamShoot.png');
    game.load.image('star','pics/star.png');
}

var cone;
var text;

function create() {    
    back = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'back');
    s1 = game.add.sprite(500, 250, 'Shoot');
    s2 = game.add.sprite(280, 250, 'Shoot');
    s3 = game.add.sprite(60, 250, 'Shoot');
    cone = game.add.sprite(300, 400, 'Cone');
    cone.inputEnabled = true;
    cone.input.enableDrag();

    game.physics.enable(cone, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    var style = {font: "32px comic sans", fill :"#ff0044", wordwrap: true, wordWrapWidth: cone.width,align:"center"};
    text = game.add.text(0,0, "test", style);
    text.anchor.set(0.5);
}

function update() {       
    text.x = Math.floor(cone.x + cone.width / 2);
    text.y = Math.floor(cone.y + cone.height / 2);
    game.physics.arcade.overlap(cone,s1,collisionHandler,null,this);
    //CX = s2.x;
    //CY = s2.y;
    // console.log(CY);
    // console.log(CX);

    function collisionHandler() {
        console.log("game Over");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the **create** function enable physics of **s1** `game.physics.arcade.enable(s1);`
`game.physics.arcade.overlap(cone,s1,collisionHandler,null,this);` Do it   at the begging of the **update** function. you can also use **game.physics.arcade.collide(//your params);**

Here some link may be helpful - [detect collision and overlap](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/1518-detect-collision-and-overlap/)

[overlap with a scaled sprite](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/5106-phaser-201-arcade-physics-overlap-with-a-scaled-sprite/)

Comment: ok thank also how would I be able to switch levels because there aren't really any good tuts on how to switch and add levels.

Comment: you can switch levels by using *state* in Phaser first add game.state.add("BossLevel",bossLevel); then start the state game.state.start('BossLevel'); you can found more tut about this in Phaser home page in example section.

Comment: The tutorial that is there is not very good and for me is a bit hard to understand, the game state part.